# getting error with has_secure_password in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

I am trying to use "has_secure_password" in my Rails project.  I have included the bcrypt gem in my Gemfile and ran bundle install.  However, when I run the project, I am getting the error below:

```
NameError in UsersController#index
undefined local variable or method `has_secure_pasword' for #<Class:0x00000004169e38>
```

**User class**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_pasword

   validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
I have not created any users - could that be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> undefined local variable or method `has_secure_pasword' for
>   Class:0x00000004169e38

`has_secure_pasword` should be `has_secure_password`. You are missing a ***s*** in ***password***.

Comment: @user3813256 Funny, you named it correctly in the title and missed in the code :D